# Laravel Composer Won't Update/Install

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I recently changed 2 lines in a view and pushed the code to github. When I deployed on Laravel Forge (After about 2 weeks of no updates) & I got the following error:

```
"error":{
    "type":"ErrorException",
    "message":"Declaration of Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine::handleViewException() should be compatible with Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine::handleViewException($e)",
    "file":"\/home\/forge\/default\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/View\/Engines\/CompilerEngine.php",
    "line":100
}
```

I can’t even do `php artisan -v` without getting that error. I then ran `composer diagnosis` and got:

```
Checking composer.json: FAIL
require.damianromanowski/simplecdn : unbound version constraints (dev-master) should be avoided
require.roumen/feed : unbound version constraints (dev-master) should be avoided
require.themonkeys/error-emailer : unbound version constraints (dev-master) should be avoided
require.abodeo/laravel-stripe : unbound version constraints (dev-master) should be avoided
require.mattbrown/laracurl : unbound version constraints (dev-master) should be avoided
require.themonkeys/cachebuster : unbound version constraints (dev-master) should be avoided
Checking platform settings: FAIL
The xdebug extension is loaded, this can slow down Composer a little.
Disabling it when using Composer is recommended, but should not cause issues beyond slowness.
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

How would I make that error go away? Never seen it before and not exactly sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Courtesy of `AndreasLutro` in #laravel:

Try to remove bootstrap/compiled.php.

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to fix this is to run `php artisan clear-compiled` before running `composer install` or `composer update`

You can add the following to your composer.json in the "scripts" section if you want, to make it automatic:

```
"pre-install-cmd" :[
    "php artisan clear-compiled"
],
"pre-update-cmd": [
    "php artisan clear-compiled"
],
```